# getting cookie value from php form

Tags: php, forms, cookies

what do I set the cookie value and name to be for a value a user may enter in a form? and what do i use to display that value on my second page? (I can't not use cookies for this, so while there may be a smarter way to do this, I would just like to know how to do it with cookies!!) Thanks!

```
<?php
setcookie($color, 'color');
setcookie($name, 'name');
?>

<?php
echo "<form action=\"form_data.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "favorite color:<input type=\"text\" name=\"color\" size=\"20\"><br/>";
echo "name:<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" size=\"20\"><br/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />";
echo "<br /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submitted\" value=\"true\" />";
?>
```

data on form_data:

```
  <?php
  echo "<b>fav color:</b>".$_COOKIE['color'];
  echo "<b>name:</b>".$_COOKIE['name'];
  ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have your form:

```
<?php
echo "<form action=\"form_data.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "favorite color:<input type=\"text\" name=\"color\" size=\"20\"><br/>";
echo "name:<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" size=\"20\"><br/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />";
echo "<br /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"submitted\" value=\"true\" />";
?>
```

Then in form_data.php:

```
<?php
// set the cookie with the submitted user data
setcookie('color',$_POST['color']);
setcookie('name', $_POST['name']);
echo "<b>fav color:</b>".$_COOKIE['color'];
echo "<b>name:</b>".$_COOKIE['name'];
?>
```

However, you'll notice that the $_COOKIE variables are not available yet... if you reload that page, they will appear.

In order to accomodate this behavior of cookies, you can setup a redirect in form_data.php:

```
<?php 
 if (!empty($_POST)) {
  // set the cookie with the submitted user data
  setcookie('color',$_POST['color']);
  setcookie('name', $_POST['name']);
  // redirect the user to final landing page so cookie info is available
  header("Location:form_data.php");
 } else {
  echo "<b>fav color:</b>".$_COOKIE['color'];
  echo "<b>name:</b>".$_COOKIE['name'];
 }
?>
```

You can redirect them anywhere suitable. Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

function setcookie of your question fail.
setcookie($name, $value);

Ex:
setcookie('color', 'red');

echo $_COOKIE['color']; //outout: red

Comment: how can i get that to work for an unknown value from my form tho? thats kinda where im stuck (can it even be done?!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use cookies.as I know you can use sessions for passing the information of users like this:
It is the full example that is working for me

```
<?php
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('sub',$_POST))
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
?>
<html>
<form  method="post">
<input type='text' name="name">
<input type='submit' name='sub' value='send my info'>
</html>
```

and in another page just use this one:

```
<?php
session_start();
$r=$_SESSION['name'];
echo $r;
?>
```

remember to call session_start(); on each page when you want to use sessions

Comment: They specifically asked about cookies, I assume they have a good reason for it. Your code is more common, certainly.

Comment: cookies must be used when we must connect to the server and then server must authenticate us cause HTTP is stateless and it needs cookies I can't understand this insisting Suppose amazon.com it uses cookies to store the info of users and know each of them Nguyen just said about entering in the form and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone explain what baraboom wrote:

> However, you'll notice that the $_COOKIE variables are not available
>   yet... if you reload that page, they will appear.

```
<?php 
 if (!empty($_POST)) {
  // set the cookie with the submitted user data
  setcookie('color',$_POST['color']);
  setcookie('name', $_POST['name']);
  // redirect the user to final landing page so cookie info is available
  header("Location:form_data.php");
 } else {
  echo "<b>fav color:</b>".$_COOKIE['color'];
  echo "<b>name:</b>".$_COOKIE['name'];
 }
?>
```

Just trying to understand why it is like that since the user is redirected to the page on submit.